# mex transferring a vector from c++ to matlab from mex function

Tags: mex

I am trying to speeden up my Matlab program by writing a few functions in C++ and using the mex interface to integrate them. I got my results in a vector in c++. I want to transfer it to an array in MATLAB.
I know i should redirect

```
 plhs[0] to the vector
```

but i am not getting how exactly should I do it.

Comment: Have you checked if my code helps you solve the problem? Let me know if you have questions about it.  If it does solve it, please mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I've done similar things, I manually marshal the data so that it won't be freed when the C++ routine is completed.  Here's a basic outline:

```
#include <vector>
#include "mex.h"

mxArray * getMexArray(const std::vector<double>& v){
    mxArray * mx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,v.size(), mxREAL);
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), mxGetPr(mx));
    return mx;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[ ], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[ ]) {
    std::vector<double> v;

    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    plhs[0] = getMexArray(v);

}
```

If I save this as `test.cpp` and then open matlab in that directory, I do the following:

```
>> mex test.cpp
>> test

ans =

      0     1     2     3
```

which is the expected output.  Hopefully that is a good starting point - you may want to inline it, but I'm not sure of the benefit.  Btw, if you haven't checked out the [matlab mex help](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html), it is a great resource.