# How to check all the combinations of P elements in a array with total N elements in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, combinations

I want to ask how to check all the combinations possibilities of P elements in a array with total N elements in Matlab? I am now trying to use P element from an array which contains N elements, let's say array A, to test in another program. If this group of P elements fails in the program, I will go back to array A and try another group of P elements. So each time the program will only test one group of P. if the program processed the P elements successfully, it program will stop and return TURE, otherwise it continue testing till all the cases are tested.

My current solution is that: I always take the first P elements in array A each iteration. If this time fails, then I start to shift the array from the Pth element to the end(Nth element). So next time the there will be a different element in the first P elements of A. It will continue shifting until (N-P) times try. then I start to shift from the (P-1)th element to the end once, and do the same shift method from the Pth to the end to test all the different cases with 2 different elements in the first P element.

If all the cases are tested to change the last two elements of the P elements, then test the last three elements....until it finds a group of P element which can be processed by the program or all the possible combinations are tested( return false).

My solution is done with a switch function for different number of P. And the code is increasing with the P increasing.

I want to ask if you guys have a better way to test all the possible combinations of a array in matlab? Also if there is a better way to do the iteration without do a switch in matlab?

I thought about using "perms", but this function is limited with at most 10 elements.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html)?

Comment: I think that only works fine with small number of N, if N is large than 15, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. But for my problem, each iteration only test one group of elements, if it is ok, then I stop. The worst case is to check all the possible cases. If I use randperm or perms or some simlar functions, matlab will create the matrix with the possible combinations in the beginning and then I can choose to test. But that is not what I want. I want to change some of the P elements when the program fails with the previous P elements.

Comment: hi, excaza, thank you for your replies. But randperm function will give a random combination of P elements. It can not make sure if all the cases are tested after n^k times and it cannot ensure that this function will give a different combination compare with the previous combinations.

Comment: because it will says false when all the combinations are tested. If the random combination is tested, maybe the execution will not stop.

Comment: True, if N is more than 15, then memory is not enough. I tried to check the  source code of perms and nchoosek in matlab before, and I cannot find where to enlarge this limitation. It also mentions this limitation on its reference page.

Comment: @ChangfengChen Are you looking for a MATLAB analogon of the C++ [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)? It iterates deterministically over the set of all permutations without ever creating the set.

Comment: And is there no other option to test your program without using brute force ? A mathematical way ? Because if N>15 it's going to take forever to run no ?

Comment: @Lumen, Yes, that is exactly what I mean. But I cannot find a easy way to achieve this with few for loops

Comment: @ChangfengChen Fair question, then. I’m sorry that I can’t provide a MATLAB solution, but you might have a look at [std::next_permutation Implementation Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483060/stdnext-permutation-implementation-explanation), where they explain how to implement `next_permutation` in C++ (with iterators, doesn’t translate to MATLAB 1-to-1). If you manage the translation, feel free to post your answer here. I’m sure it will be of help to others!

Comment: @obchardon, no, there are no relations of these elements, can only be tested one by one.

Comment: A small example that can be interesting for you: `[X1,X2,X3] = ndgrid(1:3);
X = [X1(:),X2(:),X3(:)];
ind = max(histc(X,1:3,2),[],2)==1;
X(ind,:)`

Comment: Your best bet may be an iterative approach like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538777/all-possible-n-choose-k-without-recusion/30540738#30540738). The best part of this approach is that you can decide how many combinations you want to process at a time and then pick up the next combination later. I just did a test to generate `nchoosek(20, 10) = 184756` combinations in under 20 seconds in Octave, so it's not *too* bad, but a mex is probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

I was bored and might have something for you. [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5286517) to the question [combination and permutation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2211915) lead me to a fast C++ implementation [`for_each_permutation`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html). Instead of translating it into Matlab, we can write a MEX interface to it. The algorithm is by Howard Hinnant.

#### Example

The implementation that I’m giving below can be used like this

```
>> for_each_perm([1 2 3 4 5], 2, @your_function);
```

It’s important that the array is a row vector! For example, with

```
function stop = your_function(combination)
    disp(combination);
    stop = false; % never stop
end
```

this would output

```
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5
 2     3
 2     4
 2     5
 3     4
 3     5
 4     5
```

And with

```
function stop = your_function(combination)
    disp(combination);
    stop = all(combination == [2 4]); % stop after [2 4]
end
```

this would output

```
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5
 2     3
 2     4
```

#### Implementation

The first step is to copy the code from [`for_each_permutation`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html) (starts after the heading “Implementation”) into a file `perms.h`. Then create a file `for_each_perm.cpp`. Begin with the directives

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include <iostream>   
#include "perms.h"
```

and continue with the forward declarations

```
mxArray * getMexArray(const std::vector<double>&);
bool apply(const mxArray *function, const std::vector<double>& combination);
```

Then comes the functor that is applied to each combination. It will call the function you’ve passed:

```
class Functor
{
    const mxArray *function;
public:
    explicit Functor(const mxArray *f) : function(f) {}

    template <class It>
    bool operator()(It first, It last) // called for each combination
    {
        std::vector<double> combination;
        std::copy(first, last, std::back_inserter(combination));
        return apply(function, combination);
    }
};
```

Then comes the entry point that is called by Matlab:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // You should check the arguments here. Skipped for brevity.

    // Get the input arguments
    double *A = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    size_t m = mxGetM(prhs[0]);  
    size_t n = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    size_t r = *mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    mxArray *function = const_cast<mxArray*>(prhs[2]);

    // Call the actual implementation
    std::vector<double> v(A, A + n);
    for_each_combination(v.begin(), v.begin() + r, v.end(), Functor(function));
}
```

Finally, implement the forwand-declared functions

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9641296
mxArray * getMexArray(const std::vector<double>& v){
    mxArray * mx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, v.size(), mxREAL);
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), mxGetPr(mx));
    return mx;
}
```

and

```
bool apply(const mxArray *function, const std::vector<double>& combination)
{
    mxArray *lhs, *rhs[2];
    bool l;

    rhs[0] = const_cast<mxArray*>(function);
    rhs[1] = getMexArray(combination);

    mexCallMATLAB(1, &lhs, 2, rhs, "feval");
    l = *mxGetLogicals(lhs);

    mxDestroyArray(lhs);
    mxDestroyArray(rhs[1]);

    return l;
}
```

Finally, compile the MEX file with

```
mex for_each_perm.cpp
```